# set up new cordova 2.7.0 android project

Tags: cordova

I am following official tutorail http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android to set uo new android cordova project.
NOw, when I navigate to cordva android distributions bin folder and enter command 
    **create project_folder_path package_name project_name**
it keep saying 
   **Project already exist.**

I tried changing path as well as project name. It still says the project already exist.
When i look into the folder, there is no project. Can anyone point me what is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets say this is a command line used:

```
create C:\Users\Ricardo\IDE\classic\eclipse\android_projects com.yourcompany.appname projectname
```

Then directory android_**projects** should  NOT exist when you execute create. If it exist at the point of execution error will be thrown: **This project already exists!**

Take a look at this tutorial: http://cleancodedevelopment-qualityseal.blogspot.ch/2012/11/how-to-install-phonegap-for-android.html, it is much better then the original one. And if you search for **Creating Projects:**  you will find this problem described and how it can be solved.